# How to check how much two strings are different

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How to compare two strings while some parts of them are same?
Let say I have a string `ABCAAAA`.

For some reason, only ONE character of the string `ABCAAAA` can be changed at a time. For example, I can change this string to `DBCAAAA`.

Now the problem is :
How can I ensure **ONLY ONE** character is changed each time? Is there a method for `NSString` to compare how much two strings differ?

**Purpose**: I put each string into own `UITextField` to determine whether this one is **editable** if others had changed. I need to ensure only one is edited at a time. So if one had been edited, I will set `UITextField`'s `enable` to NO to disable editing.

Comment: You can compare letter by letter and if they are different more than once...

Comment: You mean `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)string;` ?

Comment: I feel very disappointment about SO, no one explain, no one guide, just keep downvoting. Is it because I am a newbie? Shouldn't I get the answer because my question is stupid?

Comment: Have you looked at the spec?  (And your question is pretty much unintelligible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in NSString method available to do what you want. You need to write your own method. Objective-C does let you "extend" classes with new methods to cover cases like this.

This is how I would do it:

```
@interface NSString(Extend)
-(NSInteger)proximity:(NSString*)otherString;
@end

@implementation NSString(Extend)


-(NSInteger)proximity:(NSString*)otherString
{
    NSUInteger length = [otherString length];
    if(length != [self length]) return -1;

    NSUInteger k;
    NSUInteger differences = 0;
    for(k=0;k<length;++k)
    {
        unichar c1 = [self characterAtIndex:k];
        unichar c2 = [otherString characterAtIndex:k];
        if(c1!=c2)
        {
            ++differences;
        }
    }
    return differences;
    }
@end
```

Then in my code at the place I wanted to check I would say something like

Comment: The OP should not be "extending" classes until he understands the language **a lot** better.

Comment: good point. But others could learn from this, I guess. Still, don't you think a down-vote is a bit harsh? I am just trying to give back a little because of the help I have received here.

Answer (score 0):

[Michael L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29436119/113079) gave a good answer (+1)

I just wanted to note that if all your text strings are in separate UITextFields, then only one of them can be edited at a time. Therefore I really don't understand what you want to do with `enable = NO` part.

If text strings must be edited in certain order, just keep count of order by index by yourself.